# Object Slicing : Access dervied class methods from base class object

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, object-slicing

> > **Edit** :
>
> 1. The problem is in the **GoFish.h** file, in the **constructor** to
>      be specific, where it is trying to instantiate the players object.
> 2. The compiler throws the following error message : **no member named 'noOfBooks' in 'Player'**

```
GoFish() {players = new GoFishPlayer[2];} // Instantiate two players
```

*Object Slicing* seems to be one of the most ambiguous concepts in OOP for beginners. I have been working on this card game in C++, where I have a base class called, **Player** and a derived class called **GoFishPlayer**. When trying to access the methods of a GoFishPlayer object referenced back to a Player Object, the program tends to slice off the specific methods and attributes for the derived class, thus making it a clone of the base object. Is there any way to overcome this problem?

> Game.h
>
> > Abstract class Game : which forms the foundation for both the games -
> >     GoFish and CrazyEights

```
class Game {

protected:
Deck* deck;
Player* players;
int player_id;

public:
Game(){
    deck = Deck::get_DeckInstance(); // Get Singleton instance
    player_id = choosePlayer();
    players = NULL;
}
....
}
```

> GoFish.h
>
> > Derived Class GoFish - The Problem is here in the constructor when I am trying to instantiate a Player object derived from the Game Class

```
class GoFish : public Game{

static GoFish* goFish;
GoFish() {players = new GoFishPlayer[2];} // Instantiate two players

public:
static GoFish* get_GoFishInstance() {
    if(goFish == NULL)
        goFish = new GoFish();

    return goFish;
}
```

> Player.h

```
class Player{

protected:
std::string playerName;
Hand hand;
bool win;

public:
Player(){ 
    playerName = "Computer"; // Sets default AI name to Computer
    hand = Hand(); // Instatiate the hand object
    win = false;
}
....
```

> GoFishPlayer.h

```
class GoFishPlayer : public Player {

private:
std::vector <int> books;
int no_of_books;

public:
GoFishPlayer() {
    no_of_books = 0;
    books.resize(13);
}

int noOfBooks(){return no_of_books;}
void booksScored() {no_of_books++;}

bool checkHand() {}
....
```

Comment: That's a lot of code - what are we actually supposed to be looking at?

Comment: where is your code that causes object slicing?

Comment: Those are pointers - no slicing there.

Comment: The compiler throws the following error - "no member named 'noOfBooks' in 'Player'", seems as if it cannot find the following function

Comment: Ok - that's not a slicing problem, that's just how polymorphism works.

Comment: Ok. Any way around that?

Answer (score 1):

The wording of your question seems ambiguous to me but as best as I understand you're trying to access methods of `GoFishPlayer` through a reference to a `Player` object? This isn't a problem caused by object slicing, it's just how polymorphism works.

You need to cast the reference of the `Player` object so that it becomes a reference to a `GoFishPlayer` object.

```
class Parent
{
    public:
        void foo() { std::cout << "I'm a parent" << std::endl; }
};

class Derived : public Parent
{
    public:
        void bar() { std::cout << "I'm a derived" << std::endl; }
};


int main()
{
    Derived d;

    // reference to a derived class stored as a prent reference
    // you can't access derived methods through this
    Parent& p_ref = d;
    // this won't work
    // p_ref.bar();

    Derived& d_ref = static_cast<Derived&>(p_ref);
    // this works
    d_ref.bar();
}
```

This only works if you definitely know that `p_ref` is actually of type `Derived`, or that it is of a type that inherits from `Derived`. If you can't be sure you need to do a runtime check using `dynamic_cast` and then catch any `std::bad_cast` exceptions that are thrown.

Comment: But in general, one shouldn't be doing this.  (i.e. it's bad design to store pointers-to-base if you actually need to be accessing derived members.)

Comment: Sometimes it is unavoidable, though in such situations I'd prefer the base to implement the full interface with virtual methods so that there is no need to dynamic_cast.